# Updating 10 different fields of the same document in Firestore. Does the order matter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I will run **10 updates on different fields of a single document** in Firestore.

```
someDocRef.update({
  [field_1]: "value1"
});

someDocRef.update({
  [field_2]: "value2"
});

And so on...
```

What is really going to happen:

```
// PSEUDO CODE

1. An admin script will update 10 documents

2. A cloud function with a Firestore trigger will run 10 times 
because of those 10 doc updates

3. On each run, that cloud function will fire an update for a 
different field of the SAME DOCUMENT
```

**QUESTION**

The cloud function will run 10 times and update 10 different fields of the same object. I cannot be 100% in which order it will happen, right? Does the order of those 10 updates matter? I know it would matter if the update were to be done to the same field, but in this situation, each update will be on a different field. Do I need to make it as a transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not be guaranteed an order of execution for **any** background Cloud Function trigger that happens in response to things that happen in other products, include Firestore document updates.

I can't determine for you if the order matters for your application - that's up to you to decide.

Consider instead performing all the changes in a single update.  You don't need a transaction to update multiple fields in the same document.  The API allows for you to update multiple fields with a single update.  [Transactions and batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) are used when you want to affect *multiple documents* at the same time.